# how to align the content of a box

Tags: html, css

I have two paragraphs in my html as the code shows:

```
<div class="mainhead">
    <p class="paragraph">This is a paragraph</p>
    <div class="info">
            <p><span class="infomail">info@zazzoo.co.za</span> <span class="infonumber">082 888 7385 </span></p>
        </div>  
</div><!-- end of mainhead -->
```

And the following is the css:

```
.mainhead {
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.info{
  text-align: right;
}
.mainhead .parapgraph{
    text-align: center;
}
```

How can I align the div info to the far right and keep the paragraph in the center?

Here goes also my jsfiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/60a8qw5L/

Comment: You seem to have spelled paragraph wrong in your selector `.mainhead .parapgraph`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `p` perfectly centered and not affected by  width of `.info` you can use `position: absolute` and then just add `float: right` on `.info`. You can also use `overflow: hidden` to clear float and fix height.

```css
.mainhead {
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.mainhead > p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}
.info {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainhead">
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <div class="info">
    <p><span class="infomail">info@zazzoo.co.za</span>  <span class="infonumber">082 888 7385 </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to center the `paragraph` in space that is left when you subtract width of `.info` then you can use `Flexbox` and add margins `auto`

```css
.mainhead {
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  display: flex;
}
.mainhead > p, .info {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainhead">
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <div class="info">
    <p><span class="infomail">info@zazzoo.co.za</span>  <span class="infonumber">082 888 7385 </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also works perfectly with everything aligned as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this

You can also add class to `p` tag to avoid inline style.

```
<div class="mainhead">  
    <div class="info">
        <p style=" display: inline-block;">This is a paragraph</p>
        <p style="float: right; display: inline-block;"><span class="infomail">info@zazzoo.co.za</span> <span class="infonumber">082 888 7385 </span></p>
    </div>
</div>

.info {
    text-align: center;
        background-color: #d9edf7;
}
```

Comment: It centers the paragraph and puts the info on the right. The problem is that they are not in the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution with flexbox. Check the code below:

```css
.mainhead {
      background-color: #d9edf7;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.mainhead p:first-child { flex: 1; text-align: center; }
.info{
 text-align: right;
  flex: none;
}
.mainhead img{
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainhead">
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
     <div class="info">
      <p><span class="infomail">info@zazzoo.co.za</span> <span class="infonumber">082 888 7385 </span></p>
     </div>
    </div>
```

You can add some max-width to the info DIV.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: absoute` and `right: 0px` to put it on the far right.

```
.info{
     position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

And for the paragraph, you can use `text-align: center;`

```
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Like you can see in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/davidgourde/afsoq8du/

You can use `float: right` if you want to have both of them on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.mainhead {
    background-color: #d9edf7;
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
}
p{
  text-align:center;/*Use this for both p tag text-align center*/
}
.info{
    float:right;
    width:100%;
    /*text-align:center;*/ /*Use this if you want p text-align center of .info p tag*/
}
```